# 各カラムごとのデータをラベルで色分けしながら1枚の散布図に出力したい

Tags: python3, r, pandas, matplotlib

PythonやRのデータフレームで、各カラムのデータがある程度同じスケールにあるとき
それぞれのデータをラベルで色分けしながら1枚の散布図で出力するにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか?

irisデータによるサンプル
https://gist.github.com/netj/8836201
上記のリンク先のCSVファイルを下の画像のように出力したいと考えています。[image: 出力したい散布図の例]

画像は下記のサイトのものを使用しています。
https://blog.magrathealabs.com/choosing-one-of-many-python-visualization-tools-7eb36fa5855f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pythonの場合は、pandas.melt() と seaborn.catplot() を使うのが簡単です。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
tmp = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['variety'], var_name='measurement', value_name='value')
sns.catplot(x='value', y='measurement', hue='variety', data=tmp)
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

たぶん欲しい回答とちがうかもだけど、力業だとこんな感じ？ scatterで何度も描けば重ね描きになるのでそれで行けると思います。テクニカルなやり方はちょっと私にはスキル不足。最近使い始めたばかりなので勉強中です。

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
    l = {}
    df[0] = 1
    df[1] = 2
    df[2] = 3
    df[3] = 4
    l['Setosa']= df[df['variety'].isin(['Setosa'])]
    l['Versicolor'] = df[df['variety'].isin(['Versicolor'])]
    l['Virginica'] = df[df['variety'].isin(['Virginica'])]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    label = ['petal.width','petal.length','sepal.width','sepal.length']
    for ix,c in [('Setosa','blue'), ('Versicolor','green'), ('Virginica','red')]:
        for i in range(3):
            ax.scatter(l[ix][label[i]].values, l[ix][i].values,c=c,alpha=0.3,edgecolors='face')
        ax.scatter(l[ix][label[3]].values, l[ix][3].values,c=c,alpha=0.3,edgecolors='face',label=ix)

    ax.set_xlabel('value')
    ax.set_ylabel('measurement')
    ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
    ax.set_yticks([1,2,3,4])
    ax.set_yticklabels(label)
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 9)
    ax.set_xticks([0,2,4,6,8])
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Seabornさんは、matplotlibのテーマ集みたいなものと思ったら結構いろいろとできるんですね。勉強になります。